# How to run CoffeeScript project from the command line

Tags: node.js, npm, coffeescript

I am trying to compile and run the following project from the command line the way it's described in the README

https://github.com/slang800/twitter-screen-scrape

I have npm and coffee installed but don't see any options to build the project in such a way that it can be run from the command line, like the following:

$ twitter-screen-scrape --username carrot --no-retweets

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps:-

**To install the twitter scrape and coffee script packages**

```
npm i -g twitter-screen-scrape
npm install -g coffee-script
```

**To check whether twitter-screen-scrape package is installed successfully**

```
twitter-screen-scrape --version
```

**Version:-**
    1.0.2

**To check whether coffee script is installed successfully**

```
coffee --version
```

**Version:-**

```
CoffeeScript version 1.10.0
```

**Execute the below command:-**

```
twitter-screen-scrape --username carrot --no-retweets
```

You should see the JSON documents in CLI.

Answer (score 0):

This project has a `bin` entry in its `package.json` : https://github.com/slang800/twitter-screen-scrape/blob/master/package.json#L7

Therefore, if you install it globally through npm, you should have access  to it in your terminal:

`npm i -g twitter-screen-scrape`